# Запись в ветку реестра Local Machine через C#

Tags: c#, реестр

Не проходит запись в реестр по пути:

```
RegistryKey CreateRun = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer", true);
```

VS запущен от админа. Ошибок нет, но и запись не появляется. Фулл код

```
RegistryKey CreateRun = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer", true);

CreateRun.SetValue("test", "test", RegistryValueKind.String);
CreateRun.Close();
```

Comment: в другие ветки норм пишется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас собрано 32-х битное приложение (или платформа указана x86, или в свойствах проекта стоит Prefer 32 Bit), и для него срабатывает редирект реестра из `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` в `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node`. Соберите как x64, и все заработает.